# FlowDocumentScrollViewer Реализация сенсорной прокрутки

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

`FlowDocumentScrollViewer` не поддерживает сенсорную прокрутку - вместо это происходит выделение текста в дочернем `FlowDocument` элементе. Вопрос каким образом отключить это выделение и реализовать стандартную сенсорную прокрутку `ScrollViewer`. Я пробовал найти в дочерних элементах `ScrollViewer` и установить свойство `PanningMode` как `Both`, однако это не дало результата. Можно конечно попробовать обрабатывать события `PreviewStylusDown`, `PreviewStylusUp`, `PreviewStylusMove` изменяя `VerticalOffset` в зависимости от движения пальца по экрану, но тогда мы теряем движение по инерции, да и выделение текста при это никуда не девается. Есть у кого идеи как это можно сделать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57694151/12888024 быть может это чем-то поможет

Comment: Чтобы отключить выделение, можно просто устанавливать e.Handled = true, чтобы event не доходил внутрь.

Comment: В качестве идеи, почему не положить сверху прозрачный ScrollViewer с нужным поведением, и синхронизировать его VeritcalOffset с FlowDocument-ом?

Comment: _"положить сверху прозрачный ScrollViewer с нужным поведением, и синхронизировать его"_ - Стоит попробовать.

Comment: _"можно просто устанавливать e.Handled = true, чтобы event не доходил"_ - Я это пробовал и это не работает почему то, текст выделяется всё равно.

Comment: Я поместил `FlowDocumentScrollViewer` в `ScrollViewer` и обрабатываю событие `ScrollChanged`. Это позволило реализовать сенсорную прокрутку, но прокрутка мышкой перестала работать.

Comment: @VladD Есть другие идеи?

Comment: @D.Stark: Странно, а вы ловите именно Preview-ивенты? Должно не пропускать.

Comment: @D.Stark: А если подписаться у ScrollViewer на мышиные ивенты типа скролла и пропагировать их (просто вызывать) на FlowDocumentScrollViewer-е?

Comment: @VladD _"Странно, а вы ловите именно Preview-ивенты?"_ - Да. _"подписаться у ScrollViewer на мышиные ивенты типа скролла и пропагировать их (просто вызывать) на FlowDocumentScrollViewer-е"_ - Выпадает `StackOverflowException` через несколько попыток. Так даже и сенсорная прокрутка пропадает. Вы ведь имеете ввиду вызов `FlowDocumentScrollViewer.RaiseEvent` в `PreviewMouse..` событиях?